# Deleting certain month from certain year in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating macro which will loop through column F and will delete month april from 2013. It seem that the macro is deleting all :-D. I dont know how to set it to delete only my criteria I tried `(Month(Now) - 2)`. Mine date of format looks like `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Thank you for your help.

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim rgFoundCell As Range
    Dim toBeDeted As Range
    Dim firstAddress

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F")
        Set rgFoundCell = .Find(What:=(Month(Now) - 2))

        If Not rgFoundCell Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = rgFoundCell.Address

            Do
                If toBeDeted Is Nothing Then
                    Set toBeDeted = rgFoundCell.EntireRow
                Else
                    Set toBeDeted = Union(toBeDeted, rgFoundCell.EntireRow)
                End If

                Set rgFoundCell = .FindNext(rgFoundCell)
                If rgFoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do

            Loop While rgFoundCell.Address <> firstAddress

        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Not toBeDeted Is Nothing Then _
        toBeDeted.Delete ' Delete


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use .Find in the way you think - it is only able to do text match or number match comparisons. This leaves you with having to cycle through each cell in the range and run your comparison explicitly on each cell

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim toBeDeleted As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F")
        For Each c In .Cells
            If Month(c.Value) = 3 And Year(c.Value) = 2013 Then                
                If toBeDeleted Is Nothing Then
                    Set toBeDeleted = c.EntireRow
                Else
                    Set toBeDeleted = Union(toBeDeleted, c.EntireRow)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    If Not toBeDeleted Is Nothing Then _
        toBeDeleted.Delete ' Delete

End Sub
```

You might want to consider running the function on a more refined range than the full F column or use an end of data marker like checking for a blank row to stop the loop.

Comment: your code is working :-) I will try it on normal sample of dates

Comment: I've updated the original answer with a test for year

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Test1()
    On Error GoTo e
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim firstAddress

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").End(xlDown))
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    While i <= rng.Count
        If Month(CDate(rng(i))) = 4 And Year(CDate(rng(i))) = 2014 Then
            rng (i).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
x:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
e:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
    Resume x
End Sub
```

Maybe try to reduce the F:F range!!!

Comment: Hi :-), I am geting Type mismatch

Comment: delete the "On Error GoTo e". Then tell me which line gives the error.

Comment: And if I delete header its working but then I get error Overflow

Comment: this line giving me error if if I have header `If Month(CDate(rng(i))) = 4 And Year(CDate(rng(i))) = 2014 Then` and overflow giving me error on this line `i = i + 1`

Comment: try now... I have updated the code to make **i** as **Long**.

Comment: macro is running but not deleting what I need..its not deleting anything. Problem is that I have lots of data like 100kk lines

Comment: This solution will run into the classic problem where the row immediately after a deleted row gets ignored... When deleting, you should always start at the bottom and iterate upward.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett That's why I put the **Else i = i + 1**. Iteration only moves to next row if no row is deleted. If a row is deleted then the the row beneath it gets to have the same ID as the row deleted, so the iteration stagnates until it finds a row that doesn't meet the criteria. No row should ever be ommited.

Comment: Not saying that my answer should've been accepted by I'm pretty sure it's faster than the accepted answer. My tests on 100K cells show 25 seconds for deleting in the loop VS 800 seconds for using union to copy create another list of rows then delete those rows. I admit this numbers seem pretty off. Maybe there's something wrong with my PC or my tests!